# Getting nested array references using mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema of the format given below.

```js
var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  country_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  children: [
    {
      id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      child_name: String,
      standard_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      total_gold: { type: Number },
      total_diamonds: { type: Number },
      total_hearts: { type: Number },
      subjects: [
        {
          subject_name: String,
          grade_name: String,
          games: [{ id: String, name: String }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Parent", parentSchema);
```

`Parent` is the model and `children` is an array of objects which internally contains an array called `subjects`. Subjects also contain an array called `games`.

How can I push data into subjects and games array using the model?
This is what I am doing.

```js
Parent.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, parent) {
  if (err) res.json(err);
  // if the user is found, then log them in
  if (parent) {
    res.json(parent);
  } else {
    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.username = req.body.username;
    parent.password = req.body.password;
    parent.children.push({
      child_name: req.body.childname,
      total_gold: 0,
      total_diamonds: 0,
      total_hearts: 0,
    });
  }
});
```

How can I push the data into subjects array and game array?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "how can I access". What you need to explain in your question is what you want to do. Update? Get certain items?

Comment: I want to add data into the array?

Comment: Which array? There are several. How about adding some code to your question, even failing code, that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your edit has now actually made your schema invalid. As I said before, your best approach is to show some "broken code" that explains what you are trying to do. Please do not ask for a full CRUD tutorial though. There are plenty of examples for you to search for.

Comment: I recommend you review the way you write the code for nested schema and do something more similar to:

What is the proper pattern for nested schemas in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code and remove your comments.

Comment: I have edited the code and posted the info.Let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: Is there any logical reason behind not using many objectId's? Yeah i need to refer to another collection.Can you tell how to access the subjects array from my model.Iam in urgent need of implementing the schema for application.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you should make different Schemas and add objects from different models. In the parent Schema you save just the objectids as reference to the child like this:

```
var childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    child_name: String,
    standard_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    total_gold: { type: Number},
    total_diamonds:{ type: Number },
    total_hearts: { type: Number},
    subjects: [
        {
            subject_name :String,
            grade_name : String,
            games: [ 
                { 
                    id: String,
                    name: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);

var parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    country_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    children: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Child'
        }
    ]
});
mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
```

Later on you can do populate, for more information on this check http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

From the request an example body would be:

```
{
    child_name: 'name',
    total_gold: 23,
    total_diamonds: 14,
    total_hearts: 21,
    subjects: [
        {
            subject_name: 'this is an example name',
            grade_name: 'this is an example grade name',
            games: [
                {
                    id: 'id1',
                    name: 'name1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'id2',
                    name: 'name2'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For adding a new item:

```
Child.create(req.body, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) {
      // Do something with the error
  }
  else {
      // send the response
  }
});
```

Comment: This really should be a comment unless you want to embellish and actually answer the question. It's not like you lack the rep score to add a comment.

Comment: Whan i do this way.Are child and parent going to be separate collections or will child schema get added to json object of parent?

Comment: How can i push data into games array ? DO i need to define separate schema for the games array as well?

Comment: They are array of objects embedded in the same object.

Comment: In the above given schema you defined games array  in subjects array.How can i access games array when i create model for subjects array.For eg: I can access subject.subjectname; can I access subject.games.push() like that.

Comment: What do mean by provide array directly.I didnt understand the statement. 'var child = new Child();
                child.child_name = req.body.childname;
                child.parentid = parent.parentid;
                child.total_gold = 0;
                child.total_diamonds = 0;
                child.total_hearts = 0;
                child.subjects.push({subject_name:req.body.subjectname,grade_name:req.body.gradename});' this is what iam doing right now

Comment: That works if req.body is of the same format as model.What if i get req.body as normal data as we do in ajax calls.simple data object with the values.